# How do you guarantee the order of VerifyPeerCertificate in tlsConfig?

Tags: go, callback, synchronization, mutex

I have a tls listen with a tlsConfig:

```
  listener, _ := tls.Listen("tcp", ":8080", tlsConfig)

  for {
    fmt.Println("1", time.Now())
    peerMutex.Lock()
    conn, _ := listener.Accept()
    fmt.Println("2", time.Now(), lastRawCert)
    c := NewConnection(conn, lastRawCert)
    go c.HandleConnection()

  }
```

the tlsConfig has:

```
  var peerMutex sync.Mutex
  var lastRawCert string 

  tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    VerifyPeerCertificate: func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {
      defer peerMutex.Unlock()
      fmt.Println("3", time.Now())
      if len(rawCerts) == 0 {
        lastRawCert = ""
        return fmt.Errorf("no client certificate provided")
      }
      asBytes := rawCerts[0]
      lastRawCert = util.Fingerprint(asBytes)
      return nil
    },
  }
```

After `listener.Accept()` is called the callback `VerifyPeerCertificate` will fire but I can't seem to match up my `lastRawCert` from the callback to the `conn` returned by Accept.

The peerMutex doesn't work 100%. What is the right way to match these up?

Comment: i lock it right before listener.Accept() is called. Then Unlock() after VerifyPeerCertificate is done. But lastRawCert still isn't right.

Comment: ["VerifyPeerCertificate receives the raw ASN.1 certificates provided by the peer."](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config.VerifyPeerCertificate) In other words, rawCerts is entirely controlled by the client and you have no control over the order. The only thing you can rely on is that they can be decoded, since normal certificate validation already happened (checking expiration, trust anchors and whatnot). // This mutex usage is doomed to fail, because VerifyPeerCertificate is not guaranteed to be called for every connection.

Comment: ok how then do I make sure that an iot device with device_id ABC123 is connecting with its specific cert that was made just for that device and NOT ABC124? After TLS handshake it will send its device_id. The device_id is also in the  subjectAltName of the cert.

Comment: You inspect the leaf certs in verifiedChains for one that identifies the device correctly. I don't recall where the leaf certs are in each chain, but they are either at index 0 or the last index. And since it wasn't clear, I think: rawCerts includes certs that could not be linked to a trusted CA, so relying on these for any sort of authentication is incorrect.

Comment: but i have the same problem with the callback that is giving me the verifiedChains. I don't know the device_id the connection is claiming to be yet. I need to store this somehow and then after handshake and the device_id is sent, compare then.

Comment: "I don't know the device_id the connection is claiming to be yet." The device ID claim should be part of the presented leaf certificate, typically in the Subject or one of the Subject Alternate Names. I don't really understand what you want to compare it to. In VerifyPeerCertificate you know that the client possesses the matching private key for the leaf certificate in verifiedChains. What more do you need?

Comment: If you want to compare the claim in the certificate to something that is sent over the encrypted connection (i.e. after the handshake), use [tls.Conn.ConnectionState](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Conn.ConnectionState) instead of VerifyPeerCertificate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256712/discussion-between-andrew-arrow-and-peter).

Answer (score 0):

My trouble was I didn't know about:

```
cs := conn.(*tls.Conn).ConnectionState()
asBytes := cs.PeerCertificates[0].Raw
```

I can use that and don't even need a callback!
Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/603316/peter